# Get ripple effect in RecyclerView with items containing another background color

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ripple, rippledrawable

I need a simple ripple effect in my RecyclerView elements, which have a background color set. Since they have a background color(blue) set already, I can't set the background to the drawable/ripple.xml:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/color_view_pressed"> <!-- ripple color -->

<item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
<!-- normal color -->
```

So I changed my ripple.xml to:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/color_view_pressed"> <!-- ripple color -->

<item android:drawable="@android:color/blue"/>
<!-- normal color -->
```

It still doesn't work. :(
EDIT:
Apparently, the ripple color is getting hidden behind the background color, so it is almost not to be seen. But one can see a tinge of it in the background(if I set color_view_pressed to a dark red color).
Is there any way I can achieve that even otherwise? I have tried all possible solutions out there.
Somehow, it was working perfectly well with the ListView. I don't understand how though.

Answer (score 5):

In the root `ViewGroup` of the layout used for items add foreground attribute instead of background (that you have already set):

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

and also set these attributes:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

This worked for me

Comment: So I set the foreground of the root ViewGroup(i.e. the layout used for the individual RecyclerView item) to this and background to the desired color. But it still doesn't work. The background color is correct. But the ripple effect doesn't turn up. :(

Comment: @Sid when using this, remove your attempt with ripple.xml, it's no longer necessary

Comment: Yes, I've removed my attempt with ripple.xml.

Comment: I have set the background color to the desired blue color instead.

Comment: @Sid check updated post, this is exactly how I got it working. Hope you solve

Comment: But just to be sure, when you say ViewGroup, you mean the layout in the xml that is attached to the RecyclerView adapter, right?

Comment: @Sid yes, a `LinearLayout` for example

Comment: Cool, will try setting the attributes and see.

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 `ViewGroup`s that will have a background - the top one for the ripple, and it's child to have the entire layout with the blue background.

Comment: This doesn't work too. The background color is obtained, but the ripple effect is not to be seen at all. :(